SOT 23-6 SMD marking code GC1MGR
Please can anyone help me with a SOT 23-6 manufacturer's marking code? Tryed to search but cant find.
It's from network switch (TL-SG1016D) power circuit. some kind of dc-dc buck converter maybe



It's a Fitipower FR9205S6 step-down converter.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Thanks! Really wish to knew how to find parts in this situation by myself.
